# stop/pause file poller using spring integration dsl

Tags: spring, integration, dsl

I am able to create a poller with fixed delay, but what i am looking for is stopping/pausing the poller based on flag from external source i.e either from property file or db. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

i have used DynamicPeriodicTrigger to dynamically change the period for triggering the poller.